# Trouble Extracting User ID from JWT Token in ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net, jwt

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application where I need to extract the user ID from a JWT token and use it to look up a user in the database. However, I'm encountering a "user not found" error. I've confirmed that the user ID exists in the JWT token and in the database, but the application doesn't seem to extract it correctly.

Here's the relevant part of my JWT token:

```
{
  "alg": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha512",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
{
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "1",

  // other claims...
}
```

I'm using the following method to extract the user ID:

```
public static int GetUserId(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(claimsPrincipal?.Claims(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

```
 protected int GetUserIdFromToken()
    {
        return HttpContext.User.GetUserId();
    }
```

And here's how I use it in my endpoint:

```
[HttpPost("enable/email")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EnableEmailAuthenticator()
{
    EnableEmailAuthenticatorCommand command = new()
    {
        UserId = GetUserIdFromToken(),
    };
    await Mediator!.Send(command);
    return Ok();
}
```

Despite the token containing a valid user ID, I keep getting a "user not found" error when trying to use the UserId in my application. I suspect the issue lies in how I extract the user ID from the token. Any suggestions on how to correctly retrieve the user ID from the JWT token in this scenario?

I tried give schema and still not working

Comment: What does the decoded JWT look like? (Obscuring sensitive values)

Comment: Header
{
  "alg": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha512",
  "typ": "JWT"
}

Comment: Ah, I think I remember the ASP.NET JWT support doing something weird with some well-known claims such as name. Check your identity properties (not its claims collection) for your name identifier.

Comment: Payload
claims/nameidentifier": "1",
  "email": "tunahan.ali@outlook.com",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "Tunahan Ozturk",
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": [
    "users.admin",
    "useroperationclaims.admin",
    "products.admin",
    "customers.admin",
    "users.read",
    "users.write",
    "users.delete",
    "users.update",
    "users.add",
    "useroperationclaims.read"
  ],
  "nbf": 1703600174,
  "exp": 1703600774,
  "iss": "",
  "aud": ""
}